# Wouldn't it be handy to see how much you need for the next badge?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

I was just looking through my badges (on SO), and realized there is no way to see your own progress towards a badge.

For example:
I've got the 'Editor' badge, and the next badge would require 80 edits. Now I'd find it handy to see your progress like **"73/80"**.

Is there a way to see this, or even a reason why there is no 'tracker' like this?

Comment: I could be wrong and missed the progress/tracker thing, so if there is indeed somewhere to see it, please tell me :)

Comment: Googling "progress badge stackoverflow meta" gives me a lot of similar questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *already being implemented*. See [Help us test the shiny new "User Activity" page! (Plus a bunch of new features.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) over on Meta Stack Exchange:

[image]

The feature (together with the user activity page redesign) is being tested on that site, come help iron out the bugs!